# How to get publication recognition certificate from Springer?

Tags: publications, elsevier, certification, springer

Elsevier provides a publication recognition certificate through the [link](https://webshop.elsevier.com/article-services/publication-recognition/): A certificate for published work in Elsevier journals can be downloaded from this page.

Is there a similar service available for Springer journals?

Comment: Interesting... I normally use the article as recognition, not sure quite what those certificates are used for...

Comment: @JonCuster Some universities require these certificates while making appointments or in process of promotion.

Comment: That seems very strange as there are many venues that don't bother with such stuff. Why would they, other than as a bit of advertising and encouragement to publish again with them? I wonder if you've misinterpreted something. And a predatory or disreputable journal/conference could issue such things as well.

Comment: @IgotiT - I've always used reprints (or a pdf of the article). News to me - perhaps a local or regional thing...

Comment: What about DOI, a copy of the conference proceedings (although nowadays are digital) or a copy of the journal volume? I think there are many means to claim authorship together with paper authenticity.